# How do I enable msysgit colored output when using console2

Tags: git, msysgit, console2, output-formatting

I'm having a hard time enabling git colored output on windows when using console2.

To trick git I've already SET TERM = 'cygwin'. This enabled the colors from a standard cmd.exe prompt but not in console2. I've verified that console2 can see the env var as well.

Anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Ok, wow. The solution is to disable custom font color in console2. If enabled, it overrides the expected colors.

I use a custom color to give me opaque text when using c2's alpha transparency. I completely forgot about it.

Comment: I upvoted this answer at least a year ago when I had the same problem and this answer solved it. Right now I am setting up Console2 at another computer, and same problem occurred and google lead me here. SO should allow to upvote again aswers after a year or so.

Answer (score 7):

That is strange because, with a default installation of console2 (2.00.145) and msysgit (1.6.5) on Windows7, I do have the colors (without setting any particular environment variable):

[alt text http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/981/console2.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/981/console2.png)

This is consistent with [TheDeeno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1946/thedeeno)'s since no custom font colors are defined in a default installation.

Comment: darn, this _is_ strange. I'm using different versions of console2 (2.00.144) and msysgit (1.7.0.2). Maybe that's the issue?

Can you post your git color config?

Comment: @TheDeeno: thank you for the feedback, I have updated my answer to reflect the root cause you mention in your post.

Comment: For those who only read this answer, be sure to check that you haven't defined a custom color in console2. This will override the color output of all your console apps.

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly answering your question but an important point regarding ANSI colored text in Console2. Console2 runs a cmd.exe instance by default, which does not support ANSI colors. If you change your shell (via Console2's settings) to [ansicon.exe](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases) you can get those beautiful colors. http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/forums/forum/143117/topic/1501012

If you want to run a Console2 bash shell with colors, add a tab with the following:

Shell: "C:\Program Files\ansi166\x64\ansicon.exe" c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -i"

Icon: C:\cygwin64\Cygwin-Terminal.ico

Note:  Ensure that you are running compatible installs of each product (i.e. x86 vs x64).

Comment: Console2 can actually wrap any shell that uses conhost.exe, like cmd.exe, PowerShell, Cygwin bash, Python shell.  @thedeeno said he was using Cygwin, which has colours.  If you want colours, as well as a hell of a lot of other extra functionality, you can use TCC/LE instead of cmd.exe (also within Console2), which is compatible and a lot more powerful.

Comment: yes, but to use with putty you will actually need ANSICON (now on [new location](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads)): http://blog.jimueller.com/post/29709142253/use-putty-with-console2