# quitting git log from a bash script

Tags: git, bash, mingw, pager

i'm trying to write a 'live git log' bash script. 
here's the code so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true;
do
    clear
    git log --graph -10 --all --color --date=short --pretty=format:"%Cred%x09%h %Creset%ad%Cblue%d %Creset %s %C(bold)(%an)%Creset"
    sleep 3
done
```

my problem is that git log uses a pager and you have to press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit or it will just sit there forever. is there a way to code the quit command in bash? i tried echoing q, with no luck. (i saw another post here that suggested echo "q" > /dev/console -- but there is no dev console in my environment)

system: win7 box - emulating bash with mingw (1.7.6.msysget.0)

**UPDATE**

here's the finished script

```
#!/bin/sh
while true;
do
    clear
    git log \
    --graph \
    --all \
    --color \
    --date=short \
    -40 \
    --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%x20%C(white)%cd%C(green)%d%C(reset)%x20%s%x20%C(bold)(%an)%Creset" |
    cat -
    sleep 15
done
```

the -40 is a personal taste. change it to whatever number suits you and your terminal screen size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
git log \
    --graph -10 \
    --all \
    --color \
    --date=short \
    --pretty=format:"%Cred%x09%h %Creset%ad%Cblue%d %Creset %s %C(bold)(%an)%Creset" |
    cat -
```

**edit**

`| cat -` is not specific to git, that works in each use cases when you have a pager and you'd want to print to `STDOUT`

Comment: Added explanations about `| cat -`

Comment: awesome! that's the ticket! but i dont understand why. what exactly is "cat -" doing? and why is it overriding the pager?

Comment: It forces `STDOUT` to pass by `cat`

Comment: oh i get it! i missed the fact that you were piping all of git log **INTO** cat! thanx!!!!

Comment: This creates an unnecessary extra process while resetting the PAGER variable doesn't

Comment: why mess with env variables if you can just say in your command that you don't want a pager

Answer (score 23):

Adding --no-pager is the way to go.:

```
git --no-pager log
```

So the full command would be

```
git --no-pager log --graph -10 --all --color --date=short --pretty=format:"%Cred%x09%h %Creset%ad%Cblue%d %Creset %s %C(bold)(%an)%Creset"
```

Comment: ok, that's a start. i had not heard of the --no-pager flag. but try calling that command. the formatting is totally gone, and there are (i assume) escape characters in the output. completely useless output.

    * [31m 4c29b0d [m2012-10-01[34m (HEAD) [m updated test.php [1m(xero)[m

Comment: it works fine on my Windows 7 box. You have something messed up on your terminal config I guess? I am using it with command prompt though, not through mingw.

Comment: had to confirm - works also without issues with cygwin bash + other environments. No experience with mingw though.

Comment: weird. i'm using console2 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) as a frontend to mingw. i wounder if that's causing it. i still upvoted your post.

Comment: maybe related to this, custom colors of console2? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445003/how-do-i-enable-msysgit-colored-output-when-using-console2 - though you probably don't need it as it's working with cat, too

Answer (score 2):

setting, in your script:

```
export PAGER=
```

would do the trick

Comment: i tired that after the shebang line and in the while loop, with no luck. actually that looks like it has no effect at all. i tired setting it to nothing, less, more, and askodjaskdlj (which should cause an error i would assume) but i get nothing different in my results.